# Where to change Leaflet MarkerCluster icon size in CSS?

Tags: html, css, leaflet, markerclusterer

I have looked into the CSS file for the Marker Clusters plugin in Leaflet. I changed the icon to what ever I wanted in the `.marker-cluster-small` css class. I set it to `background-image: url(....)` I set the transparency (alpha) value for the clusters to 0 so that I only see my desired icon. How do I enlarge the size of my icon so that it does not get chopped off. here is the link for the cluster CSS

[enter link description here](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/blob/master/dist/MarkerCluster.Default.css)

Answer (score 3):

The default icon creation method in Leaflet.markercluster returns

```
L.DivIcon({ html: '<div><span>' + childCount + '</span></div>', className: 'marker-cluster' + c, iconSize: new L.Point(40, 40) });
```

It is setting an icon size of 40px that looks to get written to the wrapping `<div>` of the marker cluster, which is taking precedence of the size that you are setting in the CSS.

A quick fix may be to add the !important declaration on the height and width properties in your CSS to make sure they are applied.

A better way is to pass in a customer icon creation function when you create a new marker cluster group, as outlined in their docs:
[Customizing the Cluster Markers](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster#customising-the-clustered-markers)

```
var markers = new L.MarkerClusterGroup({
    iconCreateFunction: function(cluster) {
        return new L.DivIcon({ html: '<b>' + cluster.getChildCount() + '</b>' });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this to completely customise the `MarkerClusterGroup` icons:

```
var markers = new L.MarkerClusterGroup({
    spiderfyOnMaxZoom: true,
    removeOutsideVisibleBounds: true,
    animateAddingMarkers: true,
    iconCreateFunction: function(cluster) {
        var clusterSize = "small";
        if (cluster.getChildCount() >= 10) {
            clusterSize = "medium";
        }
        return new L.DivIcon({
            html: '<div><span>' + cluster.getChildCount() + '</span></div>',
            className: 'marker-cluster marker-cluster-' + clusterSize,
            iconSize: new L.Point(40, 40)
        });
    }
});
```

Please refer to [Customising the Clustered Markers](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster#customising-the-clustered-markers).